# How to create animated vectorfield with particles using manim

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, manim

I would like to create a visualisation of vectorfield in manim like this one

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE

I'm absolute newbie to Manim and I don't know how to start. Can anyone explain me how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`VectorField`](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.vector_field.VectorField.html#manim.mobject.vector_field.VectorField), [`StreamLines`](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.vector_field.StreamLines.html#manim.mobject.vector_field.StreamLines), and [`ArrowVectorField`](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.vector_field.ArrowVectorField.html#manim.mobject.vector_field.ArrowVectorField) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks! StreamLines is exactly what i need!